# D3 transition end events not firing correctly?

Tags: d3.js

This should be straightforward: I just want to start a D3 transition running when the user clicks on a button.

However, the D3 `end` event does not seem to be firing correctly on my transitions: I've asked for a transition to `rotate(120)`, but the `end` event seems to be firing when the `rotate` attribute is only `45`.

This is my code:

```
var angle = 0;
// handle click event
d3.selectAll('.mycolour').on('click', function() { 

d3.select("#loadingicon").remove(); 

// redraw the icon (excluded here for brevity)...
// setting the transform attribute to 0 explicitly.. 
group2.attr("transform", "rotate(0,0,0)");

// and start it turning:
angle = 0;
function rotateLoadingIcon() {
  angle = angle%360;
  angle += 120;
  console.log('rotateLoadingIcon', angle, group2.attr("transform"));
  d3.select(".icon").transition().ease("linear")
   .duration(4000)
   .attr("transform", "rotate(" + angle + ",0,0)")
   .each("end", function() { 
     angle += 120;
     console.log('innerRotateLoadingIcon', angle, group2.attr("transform"));    
     group2.transition().ease("linear")
       .duration(4000)
       .attr("transform", "rotate(" + angle + ",0,0)")
       .each("end", function() {            
         rotateLoadingIcon();
     });
   });
 }

 console.log('about to start icon loading');
 rotateLoadingIcon();

});
```

It works the first time the icon is drawn:

```
 rotateLoadingIcon 120 rotate(0,0,0)
 innerRotateLoadingIcon 240 rotate(119.99999999999999)
```

But after second or subsequent clicks, I've seen it produce console output like this:

```
about to start icon loading
rotateLoadingIcon 120 rotate(0,0,0)
innerRotateLoadingIcon 240 rotate(45.14999999999999)
```

In practice what this means is that the direction of rotation changes :(

Why has `innerRotateLoadingIcon` started, when the `rotate` attribute is only set to `45.1...`? Surely given the code, it shouldn't start until `rotate` reaches `120` - as in the first time the code is run.

I'm wondering if the way I have set up the JavaScript means that two different versions of `rotateLoadingIcon` could be running at the same time. Is this possible, and can I fix it if so?

Update: Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem, though I'm now trying `setInterval` rather than `end` - click twice and you'll see the rotation change direction, I can't figure out why: http://jsfiddle.net/QtBvJ/

Comment: By "second or subsequent clicks" do you mean that this happens when you click the button again? There is no termination condition for your rotation function, so clicking the button again will cause another set of transitions to be started that interfere with the first set.

Comment: Yes, when I click the button again. But clicking it again causes the entire element to be removed (`d3.select("#loadingicon").remove();`) so I would have thought the transition would vanish too... or doesn't it work like that? If not, how can I add a termination condition?

Comment: What is the element you're removing? You can add a termination condition by checking it before the recursive call to `rotateLoadingIcon()`.

Comment: The element I'm removing and re-adding on each click is `#loadingicon`, which is the container element for the group - the structure of the HTML generate by D3 is something like `<div id="loadingicon"><svg ...><g class="group2"></g></svg></div>`.

Comment: Ok, I'm lost. You are removing the element that you're then rotating? And where are you adding it back in?

Comment: Yes, sorry. At the start of the click handler, I remove the element. Then I re-add it (as noted in comment above `redraw the icon (excluded here for brevity)`). Then I rotate it.

Comment: Why are you removing it and immediately afterwards adding it back in?

Comment: To avoid having to check if it exists. Just seems cleaner (though yes I know it isn't really the D3 way). Is that a bad reason?

Comment: To clarify a bit more: the user can fire multiple click events in succession. The first time the user clicks, I'd like to add a loading icon, and start it rotating. The second time, I'd like to update the loading icon with some new information, and start it rotating again from zero. I choice to delete and re-add the element because it's just easier than using `.update()` etc in D3. But if that decision is causing this problem with transitions, I'll rewrite the code to use `.update()`.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're using an explicit `d3.select` inside your recursive transition function. If you only operate on elements that are selected outside that function it should work.

Comment: I thought that too, but the problem persists even if I select it outside the function. When the problem occurs, it does look like there are multiple versions of the transition running - e.g. there seem to be twice as many console statements printed. I wonder if the transition is somehow not getting removed, even when the element is removed?

Comment: Could you post the complete code please, preferably in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks for all your help with this. Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QtBvJ/ (I actually switched from using recursive function calls to using `setInterval`, but the problem is the same.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the version in your jsfiddle, you only need to clear the timeout properly to make it work. The function `setTimeout` returns a reference that you need to pass to `window.clearTimeout`, i.e.

```
var t = null;
...
window.clearTimeout(t);
...
t = setTimeout(...);
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QtBvJ/1/).